# Redis in transit encryption GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, encryption, redis

i have a question about the feature in transit encryption on a redis memory cache in GCP.

Do i need this feature for encryption as long as my whole application communication takes place inside the vpc?
In the white papers it says that all communication is encrypted on a network base, so i would say this feature is targed for outside google communication right?

Thanks !

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. We only accept programming-related questions in this site.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/security/encryption-in-transit#encryption-all-regions) is clear: all the traffic, even intra-cluster is encrypted by default.